# Installing Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, installation

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu on my computer **(Running Windows 7 Home Premium)**, in place of the current operating system. I do not have an installation disk or USB stick.

I have downloaded three Ubuntu workstation via the website, and am running it on VirtualBox **(Version 5.1.8)**. I first selected to ***Try Ubuntu*** so that I could get a taste of what I was hoping to have on my computer. After playing around with it a bit, I clicked the ***Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS*** icon, selected English as my language, and selected to install third party software.

You've read up on what I've done, now here's my question.

[image: Desktop]

Will selecting ***Erase disk and install Ubuntu*** remove Windows 7 and install Ubuntu on my hard disk in its place?

Answer (score 0):

It will erase the contents of your virtualbox storage - thus if your Virtualbox client is running Windows, it will overwrite that.  If not, it won't.    Provided that the Virtualbox is using a single file or dedicated block device (very, very likely) as opposed to a shared filesystem (I don't even know if Virtualbox has the ability to do this), the only data that will be affected is that INSIDE the container.

Comment: So I have to have the bootable CD or USB stick?

Comment: Yes, you need a boot CD or USB.

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing how you got as far as you did.  My guess is you are using a USB image as a virtual CD, in which case this will work fine, as the image is appearing to Virtualbox as a CD.   (Think of VirtualBox as a virtual computer with everything - including the CD drive able to be emulated by resources off the host)

Comment: After a bit of researching, and a lot of trial and error, I found that the 'Unetbootin' tool installs the Ubuntu platform on my laptop computer as its own OS. Now, I'm about to install it on my computer, and I'll link you to a new question  in which I'll need your assistance.